# Call UpdateView without going to the UpdateView page in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am looking for the best way to make an updateable list from model objects in Django.

Let's say that I have a models.py:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    currently_running = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and I have a views.py that shows the objects from that model:

```
class MachineView(ListView):
    model = Machine
    fields = ['machine', 'currently_running']
    template_name = 'viewer/machine_view.html'

class MachineUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Machine
    fields = ['currently_running']
    template_name = 'viewer/machine_update_view.html'
```

Then I have a template, machine_view.html:

```
...

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Machine</th>
    <th>Part Running</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  {% for machine in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{machine.machine}}</td>
    <td>{{machine.currently_running}}</td>
    <td> <a href="{% url 'machine_update_view' pk=machine.pk %}">Change</a> </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
...
```

and machine_update_view.html:

```
...

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
...
```

This currently takes the user to the update page where they input a single parameter, and press update again.

Would it be possible to do this with just passed parameters automatically?

So instead of going to an update page, they just make the change they would like to, and then send the update request directly. Then refresh the page so they can see their update they made.

Can this be done?

---

Edit: For clarity of what I would want to do, I would like to add the line:

```
<td><input type="text" name="currently_running"></td>
```

to the machine_view.html.

Or something along those lines in the DetailView, which would send as a parameter.

This way I can bypass going to the UpdateView page entirely. Just call it from DetailView and it makes the update.

Comment: Sounds like a job for ajax - have you considered this for your solution?

Comment: I have not considered that yet. I am not sure exactly where to start for it, but I will start looking into it now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to use javascript (jquery and ajax) to dynamically update a webpage:

**template.html**

```html
<!-- we will use js to send a post request when this button is clicked -->
<button id="my-button">Submit</button>
```

**script.js**

```js
// using jquery, we will set the function that executes when the button is clicked
$('#my-button').click(function() {

  // launch an ajax request:
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '<the-url>',
    data : {
      someKey : 'someValue'
    },
    success : function(response) {
      
      // this function executes when we receive a succesful response from the backend

      // unpack the response:
      result = response.result;

      // update html page:
      ...
 
   }
  }
});
```

**views.py**

```py
def my_view_function(request):

    """ this function executes when the ajax request is sent """

    # unpack the request
    some_value = request.POST.get('someKey')

    # do some logic:
    ...
  
    # pack the response:
    response = {
        "result" : "some result"
    }

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Using this pattern you can create dynamic pages that update themselves without the user having to refresh.